# Problema com timer em Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, jtextfield, actionlistener

## Explicação:

Possuo um componente `JTextField` que seria um contador regressivo, porém quando eu utilizo o `ActionListener` desta forma:

```java
 public static ActionListener alredBGolem = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      redBGolem.setText(String.valueOf(tempoRedBGolem));
      tempoRedBGolem--;
  }
};
```

Ele funciona corretamente, mas quando chama uma função:

```java
public static JTextField redBGolem = new JTextField();
private static int tempoRedBGolem = 300;
private static Timer timerRedBGolem = new Timer(1000, alredBGolem);


 public static ActionListener alredBGolem = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      count(redBGolem,timerRedBGolem,tempoRedBGolem,1);
  }
};
public static void count(JTextField Field, Timer cTimer, int Tempo, int Type){
    Field.setText(String.valueOf(Tempo));
    Tempo--;
    System.out.println(Tempo);
}
```

Ele apenas imprime `299` repetidamente e o `JTextField` não sai do `300`.

Como resolver este problema?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os parâmetros em Java são sempre passados por valor e não por referência. Então, ao alterar o valor da variável `Tempo`, você está alterando o valor da cópia do argumento e não o valor original de `tempoRedBGolem`.

Entretanto, você poderia passar por parâmetro um objeto mutável e alterar uma propriedade desse objeto.

```java
public class Contador {
    private int i = 0;
    public Contador(int i) { this.i = i; }
    public void count() {  i--; } 
    public int get() { return i; }
}
```

E depois seu código fica assim:

```java
public static JTextField redBGolem = new JTextField();
private static Contador tempoRedBGolem = new Contador(300); 
private static Timer timerRedBGolem = new Timer(1000, alredBGolem);

public static ActionListener alredBGolem = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      count(redBGolem,timerRedBGolem,tempoRedBGolem,1);
  }
};

public static void count(JTextField Field, Timer cTimer, Contador Tempo, int Type){
    Field.setText(String.valueOf(Tempo.get()));
    Tempo.count();
    System.out.println(Tempo.get());
}
```

---

Outra opção seria alterar o valor estático diretamente:

```java
public static void count(JTextField Field, Timer cTimer, int Type){
    Field.setText(String.valueOf(tempoRedBGolem));
    tempoRedBGolem--;
    System.out.println(tempoRedBGolem);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @utluiz funcionou com a classe contador, eu to usando o fundo transparente no `JtextFiel` só que quando muda o conteudo ele fica tudo embaralhado como se imprimisse um numero em cima do outro, tu sabe o que ? estou usando o `background` assim: `redBGolem.setBackground(new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,0f));`

Comment: @alleen94 Não sou muito dessa parte de GUI, mas tente chamar o método `repaint()` do elemento do componente ou então o método `revalidate()` do painel que o contém.