# Rotina em Java dentro de laço de repetição

Tags: java

Tenho um método em Java que faz o envio de um email com um doc anexo, e está funcionando corretamente. Porém este método leva em torno de 50 segundos executando todo o processo de envio. Mas agora vou precisar executar ele varias vezes em sequencia. Como posso fazer com que este método rode, mas que ele só inicie novamente quando ele finalizar?

Exemplo:

```
while(diretorio!=""){

  enviaEmail(destinatario,assunto,anexo) // isso leva 50segundos executando, mas eu quero que só execute novamente após o término de cada envio..

  }
//o que está acontecendo é que ele está enviando um em cima do outro, sem aguardar cada envio ser concluido
```

OBS. se a solução for com Threads, onde coloco a Thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependendo da sua necessidade, vejo pelo menos duas possibilidades.

## `Timer`

Se você quer executar um processo repetiras vezes, mas sem intercalar as execuções, isto é, deixando sempre um intervalo entre uma e outra, pode usar `Timer` para agendar tal execução.

Há várias questões relacionadas aqui no SOpt que podem lhe ajudar:

- [Agendar Tarefas com Timer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6858/227)
- [Criando timer com JAVA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5886/227)
- [Problema com timer em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6333/227)
- [Dúvida ao usar TimerTask](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106662/227)
- [Diferença entre scheduleAtFixedRate e schedule na classe ScheduledExecutorService](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50489/227)

## Fila

Se tudo o que você quer é enfileirar os envios de forma que eles não sejam executados todos ao mesmo tempo, você pode criar uma fila para colocar dados das mensagens a serem enviado.

Então, cria uma *thread* para consumir os itens da fila, enviando os e-mails um a um, ou lote a lote, como preferir. A implementação exata depende do resultado que você almeja.

Em termos de classe, seria interessante você olhar como implementar uma [queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/queue.html) (e.g.: `LinkedList`) ou uma [deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/deque.html) (e.g.: `ArrayDeque`).

No caso de usar threads diferentes para acessar a file, precisa de uma implementação concorrente, tal como [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html).

Neste caso, a thread pode ser criada em qualquer lugar, desde que tenha acesso à fila. Exemplo de implementação:

```
public class GerenciadorEnvio implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<Mensagem> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    public void enviarMensagem(Mensagem m) {
        //coloca uma mensagem na fila
        queue.add(m);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //laço infinito - uma condição de parada pode ser adicionada
        for (;;) {
            try {
                //Retira um item da fila, se não houver, a thread fica bloqueada aguardando
                Mensagem item = queue.take();
                //enviar e-mail(s) 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //logar erro
            }
        }
    }

}
```

A classe `Mensagem` aqui é apenas um exemplo que deveria conter todas as informações necessários para enviar um e-mail ou um grupo de e-mails.

Exemplo de uso:

```
GerenciadorEnvio ge = new GerenciadorEnvio();
new Thread(ge).start();
ge.postarMensagem(new Mensagem(...));
```

Neste caso, você pode enviar quantas mensagens quiser. Se não houver mensagens, a *thread* no método `run` vai ficar aguardando, bloqueada pelo método `take`.

Quando uma nova mensagem for adicionada à fila, a *thread* vai ser desbloqueada e executar o trecho que envia o e-mail.

Após acabar o processo, a o laço volta no princípio e verifica se há mais mensagens a serem enviadas. Em caso negativo, a *thread* fica aguardando, em caso positivo ela pega a próxima mensagem e processa.

Answer (score -1):

Primeiramente seria interessante ter certeza que a sua abordagem é de fato a melhor pra essa situação, é preciso enviar o mesmo e-mail 50 vezes? Não é mais fácil (e menos custoso) enviar um único e-mail para 50 endereços diferentes através de cópia oculta, assim cada endereço receberia como se fosse o único?
Se você decidir fazer isso através de Threads (e enviar 50 e-mails...) então uma nova Thread é criada dentro do laço, onde você está chamando o método de enviar e-mails.

Comment: Olá Guilherme, eu preciso enviar vários e-mails para destinatários diferentes e cada um associado a um arquivo anexo diferente. Tenho uma pasta com os anexos e preciso fazer isso diariamente, nesta pasta serão gravados os arquivos que terei que enviar por e-mail, minha ideia é varrer esta pasta com aquele método de envio e a cada envio deletar da pasta o arquivo que foi enviado, e quando ela estiver vazia o laço acaba...